# Manually inserting or updating a row with timestamps, without Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to insert or update a row that has `created_at` and `last_update` timestamps.

`created_at` should only be set when the record is created while `last_update` is updated whenever the record is updated.

I am not using Eloquent in this case, so I can't use methods like `updateOrCreate()`. Also, using Query Builder's `updateOrInsert()` won't work here as I must not change the value of `created_at`.

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
$row = DB::table('some_table')
    ->where('last_update', '>=', now()->subMinutes(5))
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->where('comment_type', '=', $comment_type)
    ->first();

if ($row === null) {
     DB::table('some_table')->insert([
        'user_id' => $user_id,        
        'comment_type' => $comment_type,     
        'created_at' => $created_at,     
        'last_update' => $last_update,     
    ]);
} else {
     DB::table('some_table')
          ->where('id', '=', $row->id)
          ->update(['last_update' => now()]);     
}
```

Is it the right way to do it, or I can improve it to make it more performant?

Edit: Not only for performance, I just understood that my above code is not thread-safe and may cause some bad effects in certain cases. I wonder how can I change it to be thread-safe like Laravel's `updateOrCreate()`/`updateOrInsert()`.

Comment: Fix that `$user_id`'s in if block.

Comment: thank you, fixed!

Comment: Maybe you can test some combination from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904853/update-without-touching-timestamps-laravel) answers.

Comment: Why not use Eloquent in this case? Perhaps it is worth an [edit] on the post to explain the reason.

Answer (score 2):

## Main question

> Is it the right way to do it, or I can improve it to make it more performant?

If the query to find the record to update utilized a primary key instead of timestamp condition then the [`DB::upsert()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#upserts) could likely be used. However the condition to get a record within a range of minutes makes that particularly difficult.

Depending on the database engine used a `MERGE` statement could be used but there is not much support from Eloquent for that currently so it would involve running a raw SQL statement - likely [with `DB::select()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#running-a-select-query). For example: with mysql: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)
, with MSSQL: [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), with PostGreSQL: [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html), etc.

## Review

The code is very readable and easy to understand. There is only really one simplification I could suggest.

### `where` conditions can be simplified slightly

From [the Laravel documentation for Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses):

> For convenience, if you want to verify that a column is `=` to a given value, you may pass the value as the second argument to the where method. Laravel will assume you would like to use the `=` operator:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::table('users')->where('votes', 100)->get();
> ```

<sup>[1](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses)</sup>

Thus blocks like this

> ```
> $row = DB::table('some_table')
>     ->where('last_update', '>=', now()->subMinutes(5))
>     ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
>     ->where('comment_type', '=', $comment_type)
>     ->first();
> ```

Can be updated like this:

```
$row = DB::table('some_table')
    ->where('last_update', '>=', now()->subMinutes(5))
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->where('comment_type', $comment_type)
    ->first();
```